# AngularJS variable scope, JavaScript variable scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, variables, scope

var users = [];

```
Services.get(value).$loaded().then(function(data){

        users.push(data);
        // Taken data = [{name:"Jay",age:20}];
        console.log(users) // I get users = [{name:"Jay",age:20}]
});

console.log(users);
```

Hint: The function "Services" is getting it data from a web service.

// But I get an empty (users = []) for the second console.log, I guess the answer should be [{name:"Jay",age:20}] since I have use push in the function.Is it that the push function is not working. PLEASE HELP

Answer (score 1):

Your `push` is inside the `then` promise callback which runs when whatever `$loaded` does is finished.

Your first line of code runs immediately and returns that's why `users` is empty the first time.

Here is a cartoon to explain promises:

http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html

Answer (score 0):

The service's get method is asynchronous -- evident because it returns a promise object to which you chain a success callback to push the results of the get function into the user's array. Because asynchronous calls execute outside the normal flow, the second console.log is executed before the success callback.

The first callback is inside the success callback, so it gets executed until AFTER the get request completes and you push your user into the array, so that one should log the user in the array.

Comment: what do you guys suggest I do

Comment: What are you trying to solve? You are correctly fetching your user.